# Excel file attached to email from python script forces launching excel on Mobile devices. Can the Excel version be changed 2016 ? .xlsx file format?

Tags: python, alteryx

Excel file attached to email from python automated job forces launching excel on Mobile devices. Can the Excel version be changed to something newer (e.g., Excel 2016? .xlsx file format?

Details -

Our Python Automated job that sends email with an excel attachment ( report results from API call ). The Excel file attached to this automated report email forces launching Excel on mobile devices. Can the Excel version be changed to something newer (e.g., Excel 2016? .xlsx file format?) such that clicking on the attachment in the email doesn't error out and then force a launch of Excel separately.
We use pandas' data frame to get data into excel file.

Thank you for your help. Happy to provide more details as needed

This was an original issue from Alteryx Job which was used to produce this excel and send email as attachment.

We are moved from Alteryx to Python script and issue remain same. Can we have any options to get rid of this issue in python.